# Many server queries or not, for a single web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, webfocus

I'm new to web app development, and I try to make it as fast as possible.
I have 2 choices:

- I can fetch all the data from the database one by one every time I require a refresh from the app,
- Or I can fetch all the data in an array an work with the data "locally". The size of the array is around 800kb so it shouldn't be a big deal for the browser's cache.

I'm working with WebFocus, and the requests are made in pure SQL.

Comment: If you need all the data at t=0, get all the data then. If you only need to work with more data sometimes, lazy loading might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no problem for a SQL Server to deliver the data each time.

Just make sure, that you only fetch the data you need and that you connect only once to your SQL server.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! :)